# vuejs muestra los corchetes en el navegador

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola el problema es el siguiente cuando intento tenderizer información del js al html file  para mostrarla con vuejs muestra los corchetes en el navegador como si no estuviera recibiendo información , tengo vue instalado global en npm

**JS**

```
    new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello world'
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app" v-cloak>
    <!--This markup will be the template of the root instance-->
    <h1>My Vue.js App</h1>
    <p >{{message}}</p>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Código como texto, por favor.

Comment: Ya esta el código

Comment: Creaste el proyecto o sólo creaste un archivo? No sabemos qué versión de vue usas pero es necesario que hagas scaffolding del proyecto [(link)](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli). Tampoco sabemos si puedes ejecutar node desde la ruta en la que estás

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega la dependencia de VUE y la dependencia del archivo JS donde estas armando que muestre el mensaje

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
            <title>JS Bin</title>
            </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            {{ mensaje }}
        </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**VUE.JS**

```
const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
        mensaje: "Hola Vue!"
    }
})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sigue dando el mismo error muestra las llaves

Comment: trate con ese código sigo teniendo el mismo problema con las llaves

Comment: Da click derecho en la pagina - inspeccionar - Entra a Console y fijate si te sale un error y si es asi cual.

Comment: Pero si dice que tiene vue instalado en el servidor node, por qué tiene que incluir la dependencia?

Comment: prueba, solo estoy tratando de saber cual es el error, si poniendo la dependencia andaba el error era que no lo estaba llamando o tuvo algun error en esa instalacion, por eso ahi le dije que se fije en consola si sale algo porque el mismo ejemplo que yo le paso andando tampoco le funciona

Comment: volvi y instale el nom y sin la dependencia no funciona